# gnu plot errors: no usable data in this plot to auto-scale axis range

Tags: gnuplot, autoscalemode

I'm new to gnu plot, and when I want to visualise my work result I met with the above problem.
My data is in a file like data.dbl (.dbl means the data is in double precision) and there're 8 columns inside(I have used a transformation file to check that). I used the command:

> splot "data.dbl" using 1:2:4 in order to get a 3d plot

then the errors always come out, my gnu plot version is 4.6, so it's ok to visualise a .dbl file. Does anyone can help?

Comment: Error messages usually want to tell you something. Though you may have problems to  understand them, you should paste them here. About the file: is it binary? Gnuplot always expects human readable text files. It supports binary files, too, but you have to specify that by the keyword `binary`.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply, the error message is exactly the same as the title. So you mean I need to add in my command bin array=x*x*x?I have tried that but it says: Read grid of zero width.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, have not seen that. `array` seems to be the wrong method, as it expects plain data of a matrix. You say, you have columns. So, tell gnuplot, that one row consists 8 doubles, and then plot it:
`splot 'data.dbl' binary format="%double%double%double%double%double%double%double%double" using 1:2:4`

Comment: I think it may work, actually I have no idea because my data is quite large(4G) then after I typed "enter" no responds at all and the laptop ran very slow. However at least no error message comes out. Then I have another problem, my colleague gave me a small file for test, which is also in .dbl and the command goes as: splot "data.dbl" bin array=400:400:400 form="%double" ind 0, which works very well. I mean it seams one "%double" is enough. I really don't know why it is like this.